Problems opening FOC motor control app in Vivado 2023.2
I have bought the Kria KD240 Starter Kit to get used to working with drives applications and FOC control. I am following the steps mentioned here but I can't open the Vivado project correctly. When I reach the make xsa command in the terminal (in the directory /kria-vitis-platforms-main/kd240/platforms/kd240_motor_ctrl_qei), the following error pops up:
error: make [1]: vitis_hls: No such file or directory
although I have checked and I have Vitis HLS installed.
In the other hand, I have tried launching the main.tcl script via the TCL console (source scripts/main.tcl), but a lot of warnings and errors pop up and the project opens but with the block diagram incomplete (image).
Any suggestions or ideas on what I am doing wrong or where the problem is? Thank you!

I have found what the issue was. I didn't have Vivado and Vitis HLS sourced before running the make xsa command. For anyone who has the same issue, before running the make xsa command run these two commands:

source /home/tools2023.2/Vivado/2023.2/settings64.sh
source /home/tools2023.2/Vitis_HLS/2023.2/settings64.sh
make xsa

Anyways, I think this should be told in the getting started tutorial since it is supposed to be ready to use by people with not too much experience with FPGAs.
